# Undefined upon get Request in Backbone

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I try to execute operation "PUT" using Backbone. It fetchs the records from the server. But neighter `where` nor `get` method does retrieve a solution (result of console.log of code below is thus `[]` ) which i can edit (using `set`) and can `save`.

Solution can be really simple but still don't realize what is wrong!

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute : "ID"
});
var TodosCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Model,
        url : myUrl
    });
var todos = new TodosCollection();
todos.fetch();

var todo = todos.where({
        ID : 2
    });
console.log(todo);
todo.set('Name', 'ChangedName');
todo.save();
```

Comment: Does the fetch go through succesfully? If it does, do you need to parse the result to get the to actual models?

Comment: Yes it is succesfully. And how should i parse it? May be this is the problem

Comment: See [the documentation for an example](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse). Basically, identify where is your response are the models.

Comment: Voila! This is it! And what now? Post an answer if you want so that i can accept it

Comment: Okay, I'll do it in case someone stumbles on the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [Parse the response](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) and specify where your models are.

For better reference if someone stumbles on this.
This could look something like

```
{ 
  "location": "UK",
  "users": [
      {id: "etc", name: "etc"},
      {id: "etc", name: "etc"},
      {id: "etc", name: "etc"}
  ]
  "someothermeta": "score",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Your parse function will then be:

```
parse: function(response) {
    return response.users;
 }
```

Comment: and important note: It would be better to do "put" operation in the "then" function of collection's fetch(), otherwise the data can be not loaded yet.